# Add a file to tfs that is accessible for all developer, but only for local repository

Tags: file, tfs, repository

We have a development server that is running TFS 2010, it is working fine however we have a bit of issue:

We have a file (a class file) that contains a connection string that helps the application to connect to database, each user has its own database, I mean sometimes the developers needs to connect to other servers while this specific file is locked by other users in other machines. therefore at the same time different users are trying to change this connection string!

I know I can save the connection string in a file which is not part of TFS or I can allow checked in item to be edited, however I would like to know if there is anyway that I can add this class file to our TFS and everyone is be able to get it from the server but only when they want to edit it, it should not get checked out by TFS, only in their local repository it changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If this is a web application then you can add the connection string to the web.config and have both a development and deploy mode. If all of the developers connect to a db server running on their local box you only need the one setting for all of the developers. If you need different settings for local | integration | quality | production environments you can use the built in visual studio configurations.

It is standard practice to require all of the developer local computers to be configured the same.